# Glass is rendering black in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

I've tried multiple things now. Light bounces is set to 76 and caustics are turned on, bots reflective and refracitve. I don't know what else I could change.

[image: The black parts of the picture are the glass]

[image]

Also does anyone know how to render it better? It's really distorted.

Comment: in Properties > Render > Light Paths, what are the values for Transparency and Transmission?

Comment: Transparency is 8, transmission is 12.

Comment: maybe share your glass object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Done. Sorry it took so long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up output node to All (or cycles),  it will not be used in Cycles without this setting

[image]

Comment: I thought I tried this.... Thanks a lot!